# Angularjs - Accordion not works as per expect

Tags: angularjs

using the angularjs, i have created a accordion effects. all it works rather that considering other panel.

my accordion have 2 panels, when i click on first panel, that should shuffle the state ( that's happening ) and need to close other panel if that opens. how to do that?

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.one = false;
    $scope.two = false;
    $scope.accordion = function( label ) {
        $scope[label] = !$scope[label];
    }
});
```

```css
h1 {
    background: gray;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1 ng-click="accordion('one')">Title One</h1>
    <div ng-show="one">Content one</div>
    <h1 ng-click="accordion('two')">Title Two</h1>
    <div ng-show="two">Content Two</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simply a matter of assignment of single variable, without any complex logic. Hence, removing the redundant function and moving assignment to `ng-click` in HTML.

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  //$scope.one = false; // this is not required anymore
  //$scope.two = false; // this is not required anymore
  $scope.current = 'one';
  // toggle accordion state
  $scope.toggleAccordion = function(label){
        if($scope.current == label){
              $scope.current = '';
        } else {
              $scope.current = label;
        }
  }
  
});
```

```css
h1{
  background:gray;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1 ng-click="toggleAccordion('one')">Title One</h1>
    <div ng-show="current == 'one'">Content one</div>
    <h1 ng-click="toggleAccordion('two')">Title Two</h1>
    <div ng-show="current == 'two'">Content Two</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hope this is okay with you now ... :)

Comment: your answer is working solution but what it lags is documentation, so can you add some description about the code. it may be simple enough for you and me but not for others

Comment: @dreamweiver: improved code by a bit,(there is more scope for improvement).. Added documentation for the change .. Thanks for the guidance .. :)

Comment: Still this is not working. when i click on the same title that's not shuffling to it's previous state. ex: when a penel opend clicking back should close, that's not happening

Comment: I made changes so that, either one or no accordion will be open at any given point of time.. Hope this answer is acceptable by you .. :)